# Exporting openldap to migrate to new server

Tags: openldap

I have an install of openldap via Macports.  I want to update it and move it to new hardware.

I've taken the `slapd.conf` from the old system, then I am trying to run it to configure the new server using `cn=config` to match the first.  When I first ran it, it couldn't find the `ppolicy.schema` so I copied this from the first server to the second.

Now, when I run `slaptest -f /opt/local/etc/openldap/slapd.conf -F /opt/local/etc/openldap/slapd.d` I get the following:

```
/opt/local/etc/openldap/schema/ppolicy.schema: line 102 attributetype: Duplicate attributeType: "1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.1.1"
/opt/local/etc/openldap/slapd.conf: line 9: <include> handler exited with 1!
slaptest: bad configuration directory!
```

My guess would be that I didn't add the schema the right way, but I am unable to find how to do that.

If I am 100% off the path, please let me know.  I'm unable to find concise and consistent documentation for this.

Comment: Migrating from *"old"*  to *"new"* is typically what people do but incompatibilities and changes tend to be version specific. What are your versions? Also note for example: https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin26/maintenance.html#Migration and https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin26/slapdconf2.html *"'The older style slapd.conf(5) file is still supported, but its use is deprecated'"* so simply copying that `slpad.conf` *might* not be the most future proof migration strategy

Comment: Good info, thanks.
"Old" version is  openldap @2.4.58_0+overlays.
"New" version is  openldap @2.6.6_0+overlays.

Comment: I'll say you need to pass first from `2.4` to `2.5` and then to `2.6`